# Sending one item list as formParam with RestAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm trying to submit some JSON via POST to an endpoint with RestAssured. The API is expecting a list for a key. The value I need to send for that is a list with a single item.

The ideal request would look like:

```
Request method: POST
Request path:   http://localhost:8080/registrionURL
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    paramKey=[param space]
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
```

If I add the param as a list or a map it still just sends the parameter as a string:

```
    String paramKey = "paramKey";
    String paramWithSpace = "param space";
    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .formParam(paramKey, new String[]{paramWithSpace})
            .and().contentType("application/json")
            .log().method().log().path().log().parameters()
            .when().post(MessageFormat.format(registrationUrl, testName));
```

Output:

```
Request method: POST
Request path:   http://localhost:8080/registrionURL
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    paramKey=param space
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
```

It seems the normal way is to just call `.formParam()` multiple times to create a list:

```
    String paramKey = "paramKey";
    String paramWithSpace = "param space";
    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .formParam(paramKey, paramWithSpace)
            .formParam(paramKey, paramWithSpace)
            .and().contentType("application/json")
            .log().method().log().path().log().parameters()
            .when().post(MessageFormat.format(registrationUrl, testName));
```

Output:

```
Request method: POST
Request path:   http://localhost:8080/registrionURL
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    paramKey=[param space, param space]
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
```

Does anyone know how to send a list of length one as a form parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you pass the form parameter as a `List`:

```
.formParam(paramKey, Arrays.asList(paramWithSpace))
```

Comment: facepalm, I tried doing the list in a parameter map which doesn't seem to work and then never tried the list for `.formParam()`. Works great, thanks!